# How can i setup github pages using an apex domain which already has an A record in use for locally hosted software

Tags: reverse-proxy, github-pages, self-hosting, caddy

so i have jellyfin and other locally hosted software setup like so:

---

caddy ->

jf.domain.tk {

reverse_proxy localhost:8096

tls { cloudflare }

}

---

cloudflare:

A: domain.tk -> public ip of server

CNAME: jellyfin -> domain.tk

---

Now, i have something called homer, its just a static webpage that lets me check the status of my applications (jellyfin etc). i want to be able to deploy this to github pages under domain.tk (apex), however to do this i need to make a cname that points to user.github.io, which i cannot do as an A name already exists.

How can i do both if you are only allowed one A name/C name for the apex domain? If i remove the A name to server ip i cant use my subdomains for jellyfin, but if i dont i cant use the base domain for github.io??

Answer (score 0):

A domain can only resolve to one address. why not use a subdomain to github.io? like `xxx.domain.tk -> github.io`